# Can I change the site link appeared in Google search

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search, sitelinks

When I search my website on Google, the site links appear as wrong. Instead of main page, sitelinks append a querystring which I used, and showing another content. I would like to make the sitelink to point main page (without querystring) How can I change it?

Comment: Do you mean _sitelink_, or the main search result link? See the following from Google as to the difference: [Sitelinks](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en). If it's the later, you can only _redirect_ links to another page, but you cannot change their URL in Google search results.

Answer (score 1):

Google recently closed the demote sitelink option in GWT. So we have no direct option to change sitelinks. But we can use some SEO tricks to create good sitelinks for your website. Try following,

1. The most important is navigation structure in website. Make sure that your website have good navigation structure.
2. Add Breadcrumbs schema to pages. This will help you to show the page hierarchy to search engine.
3. Create strong internal links to key pages (Pages that  you want to show as site links)
4. Make sure that all key pages have right title tags.
5. Create a sitemap and submit it in WMT.